# Searching in Mongo Embedded Document using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection as given below:

```
var myCollection = [{
    "_id" : ObjectId("559158f6473f6c540f000282"),
    "code" : [ 
        {
            "score" : -100,
            "rule_name" : "Account Email",
            "header" : "Blacklist",
            "reason" : "Blacklist Account Email"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5591592c473f6c540f000284"),
    "code" : [ 
        {
            "score" : -100,
            "rule_name" : "Account Email",
            "header" : "Blacklist",
            "reason" : "Blacklist Account Email"
        }
    ]
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55915931473f6c540f000286"),
    "code" : [ 
        {
            "score" : -100,
            "rule_name" : "Account Email",
            "header" : "Blacklist",
            "reason" : "Blacklist Account Email"
        }
    ]
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55915996473f6cd40b00010e"),
    "code" : [ 
        {
            "score" : 23,
            "rule_name" : "Transaction Check",
            "header" : "",
            "reason" : " Transaction Check"
        }, 
        {
            "score" : -100,
            "rule_name" : "Account Email",
            "header" : "Blacklist",
            "reason" : "Blacklist Account Email"
        }
    ]
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55915a3d473f6c540f000288"),
    "code" : [ 
        {
            "score" : 23,
            "rule_name" : "Transaction Check",
            "header" : "",
            "reason" : " Transaction Check"
        }, 
        {
            "score" : -100,
            "rule_name" : "Account Email",
            "header" : "Blacklist",
            "reason" : "Blacklist Account Email"
        }
    ]
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55942f1f473f6c7808000037"),
    "code" : [ 
        {
            "score" : 80,
            "rule_name" : "Test Rule",
            "header" : "",
            "reason" : "Test Rule"
        }
    ]
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55943328473f6cfc1000002a"),
    "code" : [ 
        {
            "score" : 80,
            "rule_name" : "Test Rule",
            "header" : "",
            "reason" : "Test Rule"
        }
    ]
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("559433f9473f6cf012000032"),
    "code" : [ 
        {
            "score" : 80,
            "rule_name" : "Test Rule",
            "header" : "",
            "reason" : "Test Rule"
        }
    ]
}];
```

I want to search on "reason" in "code" field in above document with following operators :
1. Equals - return all code in which atleast one matches with "reason" value 
2. Not Equal - return all code in which no one matches the value with "reason" field
This is how I have done it in javascript :

```
db.my_collection.find({
    "code.reason" : {"$ne" : "Blacklist Account Email"}
})
```

But I am unable to do this in PHP using array. I have also tried "$elemMatch" but that does not work with "Not Equal". I cannot use command() in my case and I need it to be done using arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I didn't tested output** but You should do something like following

1) Without using `$elemMatch`

```
$criteria = array('code.reason' => array("$ne" =>"Blacklist Account Email")));$collection->find($criteria);
```

2) using `$elemMatch`

```
$criteria = array(
    "code"=>array("$elemMatch"=>array(
    "reason"=> array("$ne"=>"Blacklist Account Email"
    )))
);

$collection->find($criteria);
```

**Edit**
You can use aggregation like -

```
db.collection.aggregate({$unwind:"$code"},{$match:{"code.reason":{$ne:"Blacklist Account Email"}}})
```

and its equivalent php code is (**not tested with php mongo**)

```
$criteria = array(array("$unwind" => "$code"), array("$match" => array("code.reason" => array("$ne" => "Blacklist Account Email"))));
$collection->aggregate($criteria);
```

**In addition, if you have at least PHP5.4, you can use simpler array syntax. Transformation to PHP is then trivial, you simply replace curly braces with square brackets and colons with arrows**

```
 db.collection.aggregate(["$unwind":"$code"],["$match":["code.reason":["$ne":"Blacklist Account Email"]]])
```

Comment: Thanks Vishwas for your suggestion but the first one without $elemMatch fails in case of NOT EQUAL operator while the second one(2) works with "$elemMatch"perfectly for EQUAL but it fails with NOT EQUAL Operator.

Comment: i.e. both approaches fails in case of "NOT EQUAL" operator.

Comment: @TanujSaxena  I didn't get what you want to do? You want to find out `code.reason` that are not equal to `Blacklist Account Email` or something else?

Comment: I want to search code.reason in both cases "Equal" and "Not Equal". However I could not find to know how to perform NOT Equal.

Comment: For Not Equal I want to return all those document which does not contain the searched values in any of the document.

Comment: Yes I tried, but that also fails. Actually in the case of Not Equal operator like [ "$ne", "$nin"], it returns all those records which just matches any value of object in code array. While I want to return only doc in which none of the object contains the searched value.

Comment: @TanujSaxena can you try out my edit please? You might need to make some changes as per syntax of php but it will work as u want.